# WPF ScrollViewer panning

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, swipe

I have a `ScrollViewer` object in my window that I want to be touch enabled. I have set its `PanningMode` to `HorizontalOnly` and it works good, but there are two things that I need to ask:

1) When the `ScrollViewer` reaches the end of it's content, the whole window moves upon touching and swiping the object.

2) I need to fire an event when the scroll ends so that I can update some UI stuff. What's that event?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

1) The bounce is the default behavior with Windows 7 Touch to indicate it's reached the end of a scrollable list.

2) You can attach a listener on the ScrollChanged event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollchanged.aspx

To check "scroll to bottom", compare `VerticalOffset` (current Y position) == `ScrollableHeight` (absolute maximium)

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the ScrollViewer like this in the ListView solved the problem (question #1) of the window moving after swiping out of boundaries for me (in case anyone find this useful):

```
<ListView x:Name="myScrollView" ScrollViewer.PanningMode="None"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ... >
```